# Obtener los elementos de un Grid.View con filtros activos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

- Soy novato y se únicamente un poco más de lo básico.
- Tengo un Grid.View que me muestra los registros de una BBDD.
- Tengo un "navegador de documentos", que me muestra de uno en uno todos los documentos de la BBDD y me permite navegar entre ellos.
- Lo que necesito es limitar los elementos entre los que quiero navegar, es decir, en lugar de navegar de uno en uno por todos los registros, que solamente se pueda hacer entre los que aparecen como resultado de aplicar filtros en el Grid.View.

Lo que quiero es que una vez aplicado un filtro, sea capaz de almacenar de alguna forma cuales son los elementos resultantes, para poder navegar solamente entre esos. Por ejemplo, seleccionar únicamente los registro con el diario "002", y que se almacenen en una lista, para luego poderla pasar al controlador de la vista individual.

[image: Lo que quiero es que una vez aplicado un filtro, sea capaz de almacenar de alguna forma cuales son los elementos resultantes, para poder navegar solamente entre esos]

Este es el código del grid

```
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Add(c => c.num_diarC)
        .Titled("Diario")
        .SetWidth(60);

columns.Add(c => c.num_movC)
        .Titled("Movimiento")
        .SetWidth(60);

columns.Add(c => c.mes_diarC)
        .Titled("Mes")
        .SetWidth(60);

columns.Add(c => c.anno_diarC)
        .Titled("Año")
        .SetWidth(60);

columns.Add(c => c.codigoC)
        .Titled("Código")
        .SetWidth(70);

columns.Add(c => c.empresaC)
        .Titled("Centro")
        .SetWidth(60);

columns.Add(c => c.num_factC)
        .Titled("Nº Factura")
        .SetWidth(60);

columns.Add(c => c.fec_factC).Format("{0:d}")
        .Titled("Fecha factura")
        .SetWidth(100);

columns.Add(c => c.imp_factC).Format("{0:n} €")
        .Titled("Importe")
        .SetWidth(60);

columns.Add(c => c.nombreC)
        .Titled("Empresa")
        .SetWidth(70);

columns.Add()
        .Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .SetWidth(200)
        .RenderValueAs(c => Acciones(c));

}).WithPaging(BibliotecaDocu.src.Constantes.DISPLAY_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE).Sortable().Filterable(true).WithMultipleFilters().SetLanguage("es").EmptyText("No hay datos que mostrar").Named("filtrado")
```

Y este el del controlador:

```
        public ActionResult Buscar()
    {
        List<Compra> dbCompras = db.Compras.OrderByDescending(c => c.num_diar).ToList();
        List<ModelCompra> compras = new List<ModelCompra>();

        compras = new ModelCompra().getCompras(dbCompras);
        return View(compras);
    }
```

He probado con esto:

```
    @{
    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    foreach (BibliotecaDocu.Models.ModelCompra compras in Model)
    {
    lista.Add(compras.num_factC);
    }
}
```

Pero crea una lista con todos los valores porque estoy haciendo referencia al modelo, y lo que quiero es hacerla al Grid.

Comment: Si no añades el código que tienes hasta ahora es difícil ayudarte. Recuerda que debes poner un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable

Comment: Así está mejor? Gracias

Comment: ¿De casualidad es Telerik?

Comment: Tienes que crear una lista auxiliar que va a ser sobre la que aplliques el filtro, es esa la que tienes que recorrer después. La lista con todos los elementos no la tienes que tocar, solo utilizarla para generar la lista filtrada.

Answer (score 0):

En la prueba te ha faltado implementar el filtro. Cámbiala añadiéndolo así:

```
foreach (BibliotecaDocu.Models.ModelCompra compras in Model)
{
    if(compras.num_diarC == "002")//Si cumple tu condición lo añades
        lista.Add(compras.num_factC);
}
```

Por otra parte si `Model` tiene algún método de filtrado implementado podrías usarlo.

Comment: Hola, el tema es que quiero que implemente ya el filtrado. Si lo hago como tu dices, sería para buscar siempre lo mismo, lo que necesito es que la condición cambie dinámicamente con los filtros del grid

Comment: La verdad que yo ya no uso C# y no estoy suelto con asp.net-mvc. Tu pregunta de cómo navegar sólo entre los resultados de un filtro ya está respondida. Si lo que pides es que te hagan el código para anidar filtros en cada columna, creo que entonces es una pregunta demasiado amplia y no es la finalidad de este sitio. La finalidad es responder a preguntas sobre un problema específico basándose en [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como te decía al principio. Ahora te toca implementar el resto y hacer otra pregunta distinta si tienes problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Tendrias que hacerlo del lado de tu server, donde haces tu consulta cuando mandes un filtro mandarselo a tu consulta y desde tu consulta filtrar y recargar ahora la grid con los datos que se filtraron.

Comment: Y cómo lo hago? mi problema es que estoy muy verde, por lo que no conozco bien el lenguaje ni las funciones de los objetos. Gracias